# Why does boost include two different versions of strong_typedef.hpp?

Tags: c++, boost

As I was building a project recently, I noticed that I got a compiler warning (turned to error) about the `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` macro being redefined. Upon further investigation I noticed that there are two different versions of `strong_typedef.hpp` included in boost: One at the top level, and one within `serialization/`.

There is actually a difference between the two versions as well, not just a duplicate version of the macro. The top level version doesn't explicitly value-init its `T` while the serialization version does:

Code snips:

`boost/strong_typedef.hpp`:

```
    T t;                                                        \
    explicit D(const T t_) : t(t_) {};                          \
    D(){};                                                      \
    D(const D & t_) : t(t_.t){}                                 \
```

`boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp`:

```
    T t;                                                        \
    explicit D(const T t_) : t(t_) {};                          \
    D(): t() {};                                                \
    D(const D & t_) : t(t_.t){}                                 \
```

Why are there two different versions of the macro, and which one makes more sense as the implementation? The one that will force builtin types to be initialized, or the one that doesn't (as closely as possible mimicing the underlying type being strongly typedeffed)?

Comment: There are a number of examples where code is duplicated in different parts of the Boost library.  I'd like to know the answer to this as well.

Comment: Sometimes libraries copy small bits to reduce interdepencies (so you don't need to have all of boost available), or just because of history: the other library wasn't official yet when the first was accepted.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y No doubt copying bits to reduce dependencies is fine in some cases (such as duplicating a class into a detail namespace). But in THIS particular case, it's copied in a way that's illegal as far as the language is concerned, in other words redefining a macro.

Comment: @MarkB, I'd guess that, given the small difference, the two macros were at one point exactly the same (which I believe is then allowed by the standard).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like `boost/strong_typedef.hpp` directory is a historical artifact.

The lack of explicit initialization of the `t` member was a bug fixed in `boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp` a couple years ago in svn revision 71183. See [the bug ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5182).

In Boost's Subversion trunk, [`boost/strong_typedef.hpp`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/strong_typedef.hpp) is a largely empty file that says:

```
#error "This header is deprecated. Please use: boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp"
```

That change, r48575, was made back in 2008 - I don't know why it has never been merged into a release. Maybe because it would break users without a lot of upside or maybe it's an oversight. That same change (r48575) was what created `boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp` in trunk.

If they don't want to break existing users, then maybe the deprecated file should just include the file in `boost/serialization` so there's a single, canonical implementation. In any case, it would appear that if you can avoid using `boost/strong_typedef.hpp` in favor of using the one in `serialization`, that's what I'd suggest.

As a side note, keep in mind that a year ago the author of Boost Serialization (and `strong_typedef.hpp`), Bob Ramey, [posted a comment in another bug ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6501) about `strong_typedef.hpp` that you might find interesting:

> I don't think the serialization library uses this any more. Of course it's still in there. I have no idea if anyone uses it.

Comment: `would break users without a lot of upside` - unfortunately if you include both files the current mechanism results in illegal code, which is worse than having to change an include path. Everything else makes sense though.

Comment: @Mark: I'm just guessing at possibilities, but I could see the logic in thinking that legacy code that includes `boost/strong_typedef.hpp` shouldn't also be using the file in `serialization`. If you make changes that then include the version in `serialization`, then you have to deal with the conflict (and generally would be doing it at that time). Note that if the trunk revision were merged into a release, you'd still be dealing with a build break, just one that's much less mysterious. The fix would be the same as well, `#include "boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp"`

Comment: I was able to use `g++ -E` to track down where the deprecated header was included and fix it, eliminating the warning.

Answer (score 18):

I am the author of both versions of `boost/strong_typedef.hpp`.

Because of strident objections to inclusion to in the boost base header directly, I moved to the serialization library.  In order to maintain backward compatibility, I left it in the boost base header directory.  I forgot to merge this file into the release branch so the warning would appear.  I also forgot to change the name to `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_STRONG_TYPEDEF`. And since then I added the initialization to the base class.  I guess since I made the split, I included a correction in version in the serialization library.

I just looked at the serialization library and usage of strong_typedef is now minimal.  I guess I'll get around to removing it entirely. So then it would be disappear entirely.

It really should be a separate utility.  But I can't really deal with all that boost requires (tests, docs, build, review).  And boost doesn't have a really good place for these small header only utilities.  I had one day hoped that these small utilities that I needed for the serialization library would migrate to the the boost base.  But I came to be discouraged from that idea.

Comment: +1 great that more Boost authors are coming to Stack Overflow!