# Simple types with higher meaning (C++11)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I often run into situations (in my C++/C++11 code), where I have a type that basically behaves like a built-in type (or a "basic simple" type like `std::string`), but that has a meaning 
beyond a 32 bit number or a bunch of characters.
I didn't find anything useful on the Internet, because I don't really what terms to search for...

Examples:

- I once worked on a system, where items were identified by an ID. And these IDs were `std::string`s (probably not the best idea in the first place, but that's a different story). What was really bad though was the fact, that these IDs were passed through the system as `std::string`s or as `const char*`s. So it was hard (impossible) to tell where in the
  code base IDs were used when searching for the type. The variable names were all variations of ID(ID, id, Id) or key or just i or name or whatever. So you could not search by name either. So I'd prefer to pass those variables as type `id_t`.
- Network ports: They are `uint16_t`s. But I would like to pass them as `network_port_t`s.

I generally used typedefs to make things a little nicer. This approach has multiple problems though:

- You don't have to use the typedef. You can still pass variables around by the "raw" type (e.g. `std::string` instead of `id_t`).
- If the raw type is a template, you are done with forward declaring the typedef (e.g. with a shared_ptr).
- "Forward declaring" the typedef is a maintenance problem. If the raw type changes, you get to change stuff all over the place.

Another thing I tried with the network port example was writing a thin wrapper class sporting a `operator uint16_t`. This solved the problem with forward declarations. But then I ran
into a trap with some logging macros which used printf internally. The printfs still worked (well, compiled), but didn't print the port number, but (I think) the address of the object.

I figured with dimensions like weights or lengths Boost.Units might be worth a look (even so it appears a little "heavy"). But for the two examples above, it doesn't fit.

What is the best practice to achieve what I want (using Boost is an option)?

**In short:**
What I want to achieve is to pass "types with higher meaning" as its own type and not as the plain raw/low level/non-abstract type. (Kind of) like having a user defined type. Preferably without the huge overhead of writing a complete class for every type with basically identical implementations, only to be able to do what built-ins already can do.

Comment: "What is the best practice to achieve what I want" And what is that?

Comment: It really shouldn't come down to "my logger is ancient C-style, so I cannot use actual types". Use your wrappers and re-write your logger.

Comment: @JarkkoL: Tried to clarify what I want (see edit above).

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: I thought the same, but then doing so felt imperfect.

Comment: It felt so imperfect. Welcome to programmer life.

Comment: @bamboon: Do you mind to elaborate on that? Do you mean the logging interface should have been ripped apart in a code review or what are you hinting at?

Comment: @Dr.P3pp3r Well, if I understood you right, people use the "wrong" type instead of the typedefed one. If that is the case then such code should fail codereview.

Comment: There isn't "huge overhead" in writing new classes but in its simplest form it's something like `struct my_type {int x;};`

Comment: @bamboon it is useful to have the compiler verify that regardless.

Comment: @sehe: I agree that sometimes solutions are imperfect. But sometimes C++ code is like a beautiful symphony and just everything falls neatly into place. Also I don't want to use that
as an excuse, not to search for a better solution. Why bother to strive for a good solution, if everything is gonna be imperfect anyhow... Yet I appreciate your sarcasm. :)

Comment: @bamboon sure, if that option is available ...

Comment: @JarkkoL: That's kind of what I did. I just mixed in the `operator uint16_t` to make it implicitly convertible using APIs like the Linux PI. But then the printf thing made me unsure. 
Probably y'all are right though and this is not really a problem of my approach, but of the old school interfaces that are currently used internally (for logging).

Comment: Yeah, `printf()` varargs is your problem, not the data type abstraction. Btw, implicit type conversions via operator overloading isn't usually a good thing to do.

Comment: Maybe the [opaque typedefs](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/08/new-paper-n3741-toward-opaque-typedefs-for-c1y-v2-walter-brown) could be the answer... someday.

Comment: I suggest you watch this keynote by Bjarne Stroustrup, specifically starting @ 21 minutes.

He explains how to enforce meaningfull types and units using built-ins and C++11.
  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iWb_qi2-uI

Comment: @JarkkoL: What are the dangers with the implicit conversion in the port example?

Comment: You may get unwanted accidental conversions with implicit conversions. This is particularly dangerous when code that uses types with implicit conversions is modified afterwards.

Comment: @JarkkoL: I am aware of the general dangers. I was curious what the problem in the **port example** is. Especially since BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF seems to roll with this approach.
However I decided to use the explicit conversion approach (after playing with BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF).

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: Logger is rewritten now using variadic templates. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an integer that's not an integer (or a string that's not a string) and cannot promote or demote to it), you can only create a new type, that merely means "write a new class". There is no way -at least on basic type- to inherit behaviour without aliasing. A `new_type<int>` has no arithmetic (unless you'll define it).

But you can define a

```
template<class Innertype, class Tag>
class new_type
{
    Innertype m;
public:
    template<class... A>
    explicit new_type(A&&... a) :m(std::forward<A>(a)...) {}
    const Innertype& as_native() const { return m; }
};
```

and do all the workout only once for all.

```
template<class T, class I>
auto make_new_type(I&& i)
{ return new_type<I,T>(std::forward<I>(i)); }


template<class A, class B, class T>
auto operator+(const new_type<A,T>& a, const new_type<B,T>& b)
{ return make_new_type<T>(a.as_native()+b.as_native()); }

....
```

and then

```
struct ID_tag;
typedef new_type<std::string,ID_tag> ID;

struct OtehrID_tag;
typedef new_type<std::string,OtehrID_tag> OtherID;
```

and `ID` oand `OtherID` cannot mix in expressions.

```
NOTE:
```

auto -function with unspecifyed return are standard from C++14, but GCC accepts it in C++11 as-well.

Answer (score 6):

#### 1. Strong Typedefs

You can use BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF to get some convenience.

It *does* employ macros, and I *think* you get to do heterogeneous comparisons (e.g. `id == "123"`).

There's two versions, be sure to take the one from Boost Utility.

#### 2. flavoured_string<>

For strings you can cheat the system by using *flavoured strings* (inventor: R.Martinho Fernandes).

This leverages the fact that you can actually vary the traits on a `std::basic_string`, and create *actually* different tagged aliases:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace dessert {
    template <typename Tag>
    struct not_quite_the_same_traits : std::char_traits<char> {};
    template <typename Tag>
    using strong_string_alias = std::basic_string<char, not_quite_the_same_traits<Tag>>;

    using vanilla_string = std::string;
    using strawberry_string = strong_string_alias<struct strawberry>;
    using caramel_string = strong_string_alias<struct caramel>;
    using chocolate_string = strong_string_alias<struct chocolate>;

    template <typename T>
    struct special;

    template <typename T>
    using special_string = strong_string_alias<special<T>>;

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, vanilla_string const& s) {
        return os << "vanilla: " << s.data();
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, strawberry_string const& s) {
        return os << "strawberry: " << s.data();
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, caramel_string const& s) {
        return os << "caramel: " << s.data();
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, chocolate_string const& s) {
        return os << "chocolate: " << s.data();
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, special_string<T> const& s) {
        return os << "special: " << s.data();
    }
}

int main() {
    dessert::vanilla_string vanilla = "foo";
    dessert::strawberry_string strawberry = "foo";
    dessert::caramel_string caramel = "foo";
    dessert::chocolate_string chocolate = "foo";

    std::cout << vanilla << '\n';
    std::cout << strawberry << '\n';
    std::cout << caramel << '\n';
    std::cout << chocolate << '\n';

    dessert::special_string<struct nuts> nuts = "foo";
    std::cout << nuts << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I ran into that a year ago or so. But I had a problem with it. Can't remember what problem that was. Gonna have to look for my sample code. Maybe I just used the wrong version (not the one from Boost Utility)?! I'll follow up on that one.

Comment: I'm tempted to say: maybe it felt a little imperfect :/ The other one is in Boost Serialization by the way.

Comment: @Dr.P3pp3r BTW. I just had a brainwave as far as string-nature ADT are concerned.

Comment: Nah, it was more than just imperfection. :P Something didn't work. But like I said, I'll figure out what it was and follow up.
Thanks for the flavoured_string<> extension to your answer. That is really good to know!

Comment: I'm playing with BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF. Now I ran into this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901250/why-does-boost-include-two-different-versions-of-strong-typedef-hpp). I am misunderstanding something or are you recommending to use the utility variation where in the answer they tell to use the serialization version? Or is there a third version?

Comment: I found what my previous problem was. It was similar to this [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631508/implicit-cast-doesnt-work-for-boost-strong-typedef-and-boost-spirit-debug-node). And some smart guy had the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14636855/3963625)... :)

Comment: @Dr.P3pp3r I tried to upvote that answer but strangely I couldn't :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    template <typename tag_t, typename value_t>
    struct meaningful_value
    {
        typedef value_t value_type;
        meaningful_value() : value() {}
        explicit meaningful_value(const value_type & val) : value(val) {}
        operator const value_type & () const { return value; }
    protected:
        value_type value;
    };

    typedef meaningful_value<struct ParamType1_tag, double> ParamType1;
    typedef meaningful_value<struct ParamType2_tag, double> ParamType2;
```

This is basically what boost::quantity does, but allows for default construction; the tag struct can be declared inplace in the typedef, so declaring a new type of parameter is a single-line deal; you get to choose if you want a macro for it

(Edited to fix constructor name)

Comment: I guess the only difference with the answer from @Emilio-Garavaglia is to note that you can declare the tag struct directly inline in the typedef; you can also use __COUNTER__ or whatnot to auto-generate a tag if you have to.

Comment: Is the one ctor name wrong (meaningful_param_t) or am I missing something?

Comment: you're not missing anything, I copy/pasted too quick after I decided to make the name match what your question asked.

Comment: I accepted Emilio Garavaglia's answer because he was first. But your "inline tag struct" hint is very helpful and I use it in my solution!